# Show the schema is unconditionally stable if $\theta \geq \frac 12$ and conditionally stable if $\theta < \frac 12.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

we consider the finite diffrence schema:
\begin{equation}
\frac {U_j^{n+1}-U_j^{n}} {\Delta t}  -  \theta v\frac {U_{j+1}^{n+1}-2U_j^{n+1}+U_{j-1}^{n+1}} {\Delta x^2}-(1- \theta) v\frac {U_{j+1}^{n}-2U_j^{n}+U_{j-1}^{n}} {\Delta x^2}=0
\end{equation}
Show this:
Show the schema is unconditionally stable for $\theta \geq \frac 12$ and conditionally stable for $\theta < \frac 12.$
my attempt: 
By Von Newman stability analysis: 
let $U_j^{n} = \epsilon^n e^{iw x}$ and $\lambda = v \frac {\Delta t} {\Delta x^2} .$
I got that : 
$$\epsilon = \frac {1-4\lambda (1-\theta) \sin^2 (\frac {w\Delta x }{2})}{1+4 \lambda\theta \sin^2(\frac{w\Delta x}{2})}$$
And I know that if  $|\epsilon|<1$  then the schema is stable .

Comment: Denote $z = \lambda \sin^2 \frac{w\Delta x}{2}$ and try plotting $\epsilon$ vs $z$. Note that $x \geq 0$. Also the schema is stable when $|\epsilon| \leq 1$, not $|\epsilon| < 1$

Comment: @uranix thank you for the hint.